# AVL Tree won't remove all nodes

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

So i have a test which removes a number of items from the list (ultimately removing all of them):

```
for (int i=1; i<=150;i++) {
    String id = "T" + i;
    Iterator<Item> iter6 = tree.find(id);
    if (iter6.hasNext()) {
        Item item = iter6.next();
        tree.remove(id, item);
    }
}
Iterator<Item> all6 = tree.listAll();
int counter6 = 0;
while(all6.hasNext()) {
    counter6++;
    all6.next();
}
if (counter6==0) {
    System.out.println("TEST 6 pass");
} else {
    System.out.println("TEST 6 fail");              
}
```

Note: Yes I am 100% sure there are 150 items inside the tree :)

Here is my remove method, to delete a node from the tree and then rebalance the tree:

```
public class AVLTree<K, V> implements IAVLTree<K, V>
{
    public class Node {
        private K key;
        private ArrayList<V> valuesList;
        private Node left, right;
        private int height;

        public Node(K key, ArrayList<V> valuesList) {
            this.key = key;
            this.valuesList = valuesList;
            this.height = 0;
        }

        public Node(V value) {
        }

        public void addToNode(V value) {
            valuesList.add(value);
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public ArrayList<V> getValues() {
            return valuesList;
        }

        public Node getChildNodeFromSide(String side) {
            switch(side) {
                default: return null;
                case "left": return left;
                case "right": return right;
            }
        }
    }

    private Node rootNode;
    private Comparator<K> comparator;

    //Unused
    public AVLTree() {
    }

    public AVLTree(Comparator<K> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.rootNode = null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(K key, V value) throws Exception {
        remove(key, value, rootNode);
        return value;
    }
    private Node remove(K key, V value, Node node) {
        //If node with key contains one or less values, remove the whole key
        //Else remove value from node with key
        if(node == null) return null;
        else if(comparator.compare(key, node.key) < 0) {
            node.left = remove(key, value, node.left);

            if(height(node.left) - height(node.right) == 2) {
                if(comparator.compare(key, node.left.key) < 0)
                    node = rotateWithLeftChild(node);
                else
                    node = doubleRotateWithLeft(node);
            }
        } else if(comparator.compare(key, node.key) > 0) {
            node.right = remove(key, value, node.right);

            if(height(node.right) - height(node.left) == 2) {
                if(comparator.compare(key, node.right.key) < 0)
                    node = rotateWithRightChild(node);
                else
                    node = doubleRotateWithRight(node);
            }
        } else {
            if(node.valuesList.size() > 1) {
                node.valuesList.remove(value);
                return node;
            } else {
                if(node.left == null && node.right == null)
                    return null;
                if(node.left == null) return balance(node.right);
                if(node.right == null) return balance(node.left);

                Node smallestNode = smallestNode(node.right);
                node = smallestNode;
                node.right = remove(key, value, node.right);
                return balance(node);
            }
        }

        return balance(node);
    }

    private Node rotateWithLeftChild(Node node2) {
        Node node1 = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1.right;
        node1.right = node2;

        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), node2.height) + 1;

        return node1;
    }
    private Node rotateWithRightChild(Node node1) {
        Node node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), node1.height) + 1;

        return node2;
    }
    private Node doubleRotateWithLeft(Node node) {
        node.left = rotateWithRightChild(node.left);
        return rotateWithLeftChild(node);
    }
    private Node doubleRotateWithRight(Node node) {
        node.right = rotateWithLeftChild(node.right);
        return rotateWithRightChild(node);
    }

    private Node balance(Node node) {
        node.height = Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right)) + 1;
        return node;
    }
    private Node smallestNode(Node node) {
        if(node.left == null) return node;
        else return smallestNode(node.left);
    }
```

When i debug my code, the counter in the test ends up with just one, and there is one item left in the list. For some odd reason, this is the 49th book in the last and i have no idea why :s

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because I **instantiate** the **rootNode** to be **null** at the start, I'm not actually setting the rootNode when the remove method is called. Therefore it well never remove the root.

Thus, to fix the error, I add:

```
rootNode = remove(key, value, rootNode);
```

To the first implementation of the remove method!

Thanks anyways for reading :)